# xpath for input based of its label

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, testcomplete

I want to select an input, based of its label. I found below xpath, which returns 3 inputs, even though two of returned inputs have different labels. I want to understand why it works like that and how to improve it to return correct (one) input element. Here is the xpath:

```
//input[@id=(//label[.='Max Driving Time_h']/@for)]
```

And yes, I know I can get the proper input with xpath like this:

```
//label[.='Max Driving Time_h']/ancestor::div/input
```

I would just like to understand, what's wrong with the first xpath ;) Thank you in advance!

Here is the HTML code to try...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="mat-tab-body-wrapper">
         <mat-tab-body role="tabpanel" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c344-232 mat-tab-body-active ng-star-inserted" id="mat-tab-content-4-0" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-4-0">
            <div cdkscrollable="" class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c344-232 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab" style="transform: none;">
               <!---->
               <div fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="space-between start" style="padding-top: 10px; flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: flex-start space-between; align-items: flex-start;" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <dsg-input-duration class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
                     <div flex-wrap="nowrap" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 15px;" class="ng-valid ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                        <div fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="start start" class="mainLayout" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-start;">
                           <div class="placeHolder">Max Driving Time</div>
                           <div fxlayout="row" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                              <mat-form-field floatlabel="always" class="mat-form-field durationField durationLabel ng-tns-c84-225 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-should-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c84-225">
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c84-225">
                                       <!----><!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c84-225">
                                          <input matinput="" formcontrolname="hours" id="h" name="h" type="number" min="0" autocomplete="really-off" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c84-225 ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" max="23">
                                          <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c84-225">
                                             <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c84-225 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-179" for="h" aria-owns="h">
                                                <!---->
                                                <mat-label style="visibility: hidden !important;" class="ng-tns-c84-225 ng-star-inserted">Max Driving Time_h</mat-label>
                                                <!----><!---->
                                             </label>
                                             <!---->
                                          </span>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c84-225 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c84-225"></span></div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c84-225">
                                       <!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c84-225 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                                          <!---->
                                          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c84-225"></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <label for="h" class="durationSpaceForInputs">h</label>
                              <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field durationField durationLabel ng-tns-c84-226 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-valid ng-star-inserted mat-form-field-should-float ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c84-226">
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c84-226">
                                       <!----><!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c84-226">
                                          <input matinput="" formcontrolname="minutes" id="m" name="m" type="number" min="0" max="59" autocomplete="really-off" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c84-226 ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
                                          <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c84-226">
                                             <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c84-226 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-181" for="m" aria-owns="m">
                                                <!---->
                                                <mat-label style="visibility: hidden !important; display: none;" class="ng-tns-c84-226 ng-star-inserted">Max Driving Time_m</mat-label>
                                                <!----><!---->
                                             </label>
                                             <!---->
                                          </span>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c84-226 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c84-226"></span></div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c84-226">
                                       <!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c84-226 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                                          <!---->
                                          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c84-226"></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <label for="m" class="durationSpaceForInputs">m</label><!----><!---->
                           </div>
                           <div fxlayout="row" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                              <div fxlayout="column" class="errorMessage" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                                 <!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </dsg-input-duration>
                  <dsg-input-duration class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
                     <div flex-wrap="nowrap" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 15px;" class="ng-valid ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                        <div fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="start start" class="mainLayout" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-start;">
                           <div class="placeHolder">Max Elapsed Time</div>
                           <div fxlayout="row" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                              <mat-form-field floatlabel="always" class="mat-form-field durationField durationLabel ng-tns-c84-227 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-should-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c84-227">
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c84-227">
                                       <!----><!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c84-227">
                                          <input matinput="" formcontrolname="hours" id="h" name="h" type="number" min="0" autocomplete="really-off" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c84-227 ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" max="23">
                                          <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c84-227">
                                             <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c84-227 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-183" for="h" aria-owns="h">
                                                <!---->
                                                <mat-label style="visibility: hidden !important;" class="ng-tns-c84-227 ng-star-inserted">Max Elapsed Time_h</mat-label>
                                                <!----><!---->
                                             </label>
                                             <!---->
                                          </span>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c84-227 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c84-227"></span></div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c84-227">
                                       <!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c84-227 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                                          <!---->
                                          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c84-227"></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <label for="h" class="durationSpaceForInputs">h</label>
                              <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field durationField durationLabel ng-tns-c84-228 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-valid ng-star-inserted mat-form-field-should-float ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c84-228">
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c84-228">
                                       <!----><!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c84-228">
                                          <input matinput="" formcontrolname="minutes" id="m" name="m" type="number" min="0" max="59" autocomplete="really-off" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c84-228 ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
                                          <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c84-228">
                                             <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c84-228 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-185" for="m" aria-owns="m">
                                                <!---->
                                                <mat-label style="visibility: hidden !important; display: none;" class="ng-tns-c84-228 ng-star-inserted">Max Elapsed Time_m</mat-label>
                                                <!----><!---->
                                             </label>
                                             <!---->
                                          </span>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c84-228 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c84-228"></span></div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c84-228">
                                       <!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c84-228 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                                          <!---->
                                          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c84-228"></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <label for="m" class="durationSpaceForInputs">m</label><!----><!---->
                           </div>
                           <div fxlayout="row" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                              <div fxlayout="column" class="errorMessage" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                                 <!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </dsg-input-duration>
                  <dsg-input-duration class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
                     <div flex-wrap="nowrap" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 15px;" class="ng-valid ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                        <div fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="start start" class="mainLayout" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-start;">
                           <div class="placeHolder">Max Working Time</div>
                           <div fxlayout="row" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                              <mat-form-field floatlabel="always" class="mat-form-field durationField durationLabel ng-tns-c84-229 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-should-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c84-229">
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c84-229">
                                       <!----><!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c84-229">
                                          <input matinput="" formcontrolname="hours" id="h" name="h" type="number" min="0" autocomplete="really-off" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c84-229 ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" max="23">
                                          <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c84-229">
                                             <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c84-229 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-187" for="h" aria-owns="h">
                                                <!---->
                                                <mat-label style="visibility: hidden !important;" class="ng-tns-c84-229 ng-star-inserted">Max Working Time_h</mat-label>
                                                <!----><!---->
                                             </label>
                                             <!---->
                                          </span>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c84-229 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c84-229"></span></div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c84-229">
                                       <!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c84-229 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                                          <!---->
                                          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c84-229"></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <label for="h" class="durationSpaceForInputs">h</label>
                              <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field durationField durationLabel ng-tns-c84-230 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-valid ng-star-inserted mat-form-field-should-float ng-untouched ng-pristine">
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c84-230">
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c84-230">
                                       <!----><!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c84-230">
                                          <input matinput="" formcontrolname="minutes" id="m" name="m" type="number" min="0" max="59" autocomplete="really-off" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c84-230 ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
                                          <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c84-230">
                                             <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c84-230 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-189" for="m" aria-owns="m">
                                                <!---->
                                                <mat-label style="visibility: hidden !important; display: none;" class="ng-tns-c84-230 ng-star-inserted">Max Working Time_m</mat-label>
                                                <!----><!---->
                                             </label>
                                             <!---->
                                          </span>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c84-230 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c84-230"></span></div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c84-230">
                                       <!---->
                                       <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c84-230 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                                          <!---->
                                          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c84-230"></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!---->
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <label for="m" class="durationSpaceForInputs">m</label><!----><!---->
                           </div>
                           <div fxlayout="row" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                              <div fxlayout="column" class="errorMessage" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                                 <!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </dsg-input-duration>
                  <dsg-input-number controlname="maxDistance">
                     <div class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" style="display: inline-block;">
                        <mat-form-field floatlabel="always" class="mat-form-field ng-tns-c84-231 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-should-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched ng-pristine">
                           <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c84-231">
                              <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c84-231">
                                 <!----><!---->
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c84-231">
                                    <input matinput="" type="number" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c84-231 ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-touched ng-pristine" autofocus="" autocomplete="off" step="" id="maxDistance" data-placeholder="" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" min="-Infinity" max="2147483647" maxlength="14">
                                    <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c84-231">
                                       <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c84-231 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-191" for="maxDistance" aria-owns="maxDistance">
                                          <!---->
                                          <mat-label class="ng-tns-c84-231 ng-star-inserted">Max Distance [km]</mat-label>
                                          <!----><!---->
                                       </label>
                                       <!---->
                                    </span>
                                 </div>
                                 <!---->
                              </div>
                              <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c84-231 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c84-231"></span></div>
                              <!---->
                              <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c84-231">
                                 <!---->
                                 <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c84-231 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c84-231"></div>
                                 </div>
                                 <!---->
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </mat-form-field>
                     </div>
                  </dsg-input-number>
               </div>
               <!---->
            </div>
         </mat-tab-body>
         <mat-tab-body role="tabpanel" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c344-233 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-tab-content-4-1" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-4-1">
            <div cdkscrollable="" class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c344-233 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab" style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px); min-height: 1px;">
               <!---->
            </div>
         </mat-tab-body>
         <!---->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath:

```
//input[@id=(./following::label[.='Max Driving Time_h']/@for)]
```

Your XPath doesn't work because it states that you need to find *all `input` nodes if they have the same `@id` value as the `@for` value of `label` with text `'Max Driving Time_h'`* while you need only the `input` with corresponding `label` (note the `.` that means "context node")

Comment: OK, I was too quick to say we have a solution ;) The problem is, that it works only with 'Max Driving Time_h', where the suggested xpath returns correct input element. 
Unfortunately, once I try the same with 'Max Elapsed Time_h' it returns two elements (Max Driving Time_h and Max Elapsed Time_h). 
And with 'Max Working Time_h'. it returns all three 'Max xxx Time_h' elements.

Comment: @PavelKudrys It's still working. Since you use Selenium find element method will pick the correct element (the first one), so it doesn't really matter how many elements XPath returns. You can try `//input[@id=(./following-sibling::span/label[.='Max Driving Time_h']/@for)]` to get one element only as output, but that just seem to be more complicated XPath

Comment: Thank you Jason! This last bit helped and now all elements are identified uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample, the following XPath `//input[@id=(//label[.='Max Driving Time_h']/@for)]` doesn't work since :

- `"Max Driving Time_h"` text is contained inside a `mat-label` node, not
  a `label` one.
- `@for` attribute belongs to that `label` node.

You can fix your XPath several ways. Don't forget to **add (...)[1]** to get the first result only :

```
(//input[@id=//mat-label[.='Max Driving Time_h']/../@for])[1]
(//input[@id=//label[./mat-label[.="Max Driving Time_h"]]/@for])[1]
```

That being said, to be shorter and more efficient, just use :

```
//input[./following::mat-label[.='Max Driving Time_h']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and xpath suggesions. First two works, but I'm trying to avoid indexes wherever possible. As for the second example with //input[./following::mat-label, it actually returns 11 instances of the mat-label. But it was enough to return /@for at the end of xpath, as suggested JaSON.

Comment: According to your sample data, the second example returns the requested input node. https://i.imgur.com/J3SVN20.png